# Pattern Design Printing on Wall & packaging

Tags: print-design, patterns, packaging

i created a Pattern 5"x5" inches (US Size) / 127x127 mm (International Size) that will be used by the client to print on:

1. Walls
2. Cups
3. Other Packaging (Still to be clarified)
4. Web

Do i need to send to the client a different pattern file size for each product or can i just send the 5"x5" inches and the Printer will manage the sizes for print on different items?

Attached you can see the pattern design & product mockups. 
Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: is your pattern a vector file? in any case, ask the printer (the person, not the machine)

Comment: Yes is .ai editable Adobe illustrator vector file. You're right, is better to link in directly with the printer just to clarify any doubts and to be sure the printing will go all right! thanks.

Comment: Then if it's a vector file, you need provide only the one file. Vector images are rescalable to any size the printer wants.  I can also see the background is tileable. That's absolutely fine. Any printer with a brain should know how to use it.

Comment: Hi Billy, thanks for the tip, yes it's a tileable pattern!) i'm sure the majority of the printers are fine, but the problem is that the printing order will be quite big & i don't know if there's any way to check the printing quality before they print the design all over the different products. I live in Ireland but the client & printer in Australia

Comment: I think you need to have that discussion with your client and the printer. Most printing companies can supply a proof before proceeding. Ultimately your client should be the one who signs off on the proof - that is, if they are happy with the quality.

Comment: Thanks! that's a really good suggestion. I think that's the best way to handle it, I'll explain & guide the client through the process; everything will be fine. Great help again, i'm really grateful to this forum:)

Answer (score 2):

**If you are not being payed** to make the design of the wall, mug, cup etc. Just send the file but with the bear in a diferent layer. That bear is not part of the pattern.

Send it in vectors, but in my opinion you should not cut the vectors. Put the full submarine and icecream but inside a clipping mask.

---

If you are being payed, no, you should prepare the file to the specific product.

But you need the specs from the privider. There are cylindrical mugs, conical, spherical, big, tall, small, fat, thin...

A wall can be painted, printed, pasted up with printed vinyl stickers or with cut out stickers, airbrushed with a mask, etc.

---

One recomendation is that you **prepare a little "manual of usage"**.

For example.

- The minimum repetitions of this pattern to be used is one. You should not use half pattern.
- Do not change the color of the pattern.
- If you want the pattern not to finish abruptly, delete the half submarines but only on the repetitions on the borders.
- For a wall of 2 mts tall, the recomended dimension of each tile is 50cm.

or

- For a wall use a tile 4x tall.
- For a Mug use a tile 1X tall.
- For a door, or a vertical oriented wall, use 1x tile at least at the base.

For a mobil wallpaper, for desktop.

This example would be a Mug 1x tall to whatever is necesary at the base, it can be 2.5 or Pi.

[image]

Etc.

This way you do not really design the aplications, but you do not leave at random decisions the aplication of the pattern.

Comment: I am paid to create 3 single characters separately and the pattern design that include them + the Bear Head front view as separate design. I haven't designed the logo in the centre of the pattern. They asked me to remove it from the pattern as they want to adjust it on the pattern themselves. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I went too fast through the posts & missed your recommendation that  are really helpful. I see what you mean after reading them. It makes sense to increase the tile’s size for the wall, the design will be more visible from distance. I don’t understand what do you mean in the second part of the recommendations when you say:

For a wall use a tile 4x tall.
For a Mug use a tile 1X tall.
For a door, or a vertical oriented wall, use 1x tile at least at the base.

What do you mean 4xtall, 1xtall? What type of measurement is? I usually measure in inches & centimetres. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer. Mug = 1x tall, not 2x. Just as an example. Take a look.

Comment: Basically i can decide how many tiles i want to have printed on the mug right? it can be 1 or multiple tiles i guess..

Comment: Yeap. Provide the basic parameters.